# geo_near not working in ruby on rails with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I am writing query like this

> Org.where('content.attribs.name'=>'cuisine', 'content.attribs.value'=>cuisine )
>          .geo_near(['address.location.lng'=>lon,'address.location.lat'=>lat], :max_distance => dist, :spherical => true, num: num_results)

I am saving data as below

> [{"_id":"4f37d63d3e4549126c000001","address":{"_id":"4f37d63d3e4549126c000002","city":"Chantilly","country":null,"line1":"13921 Lee Jackson Memorial Hwy","line2":null,
>
> "location":{"lng":38.893017,"lat":-77.428186},"phone1":"703-378-1717","phone2":null,"postal_code":"20151","state":"VA"},"content":{"_id":"4f37d63d3e4549126c000003",
>
> "attribs":[{"_id":"4f37d63d3e4549126c000004","name":"cuisine","value":"Mexican"},{"_id":"4f37d63d3e4549126c000005","name":"cuisine","value":"Tex Mex"}],"author":null,
>
> "content_type":"menu","link":"http://www.anitascorp.com","org_type":"restaurant","title":null},"name":"Anita's New Mexican Restaurant","src_code":"RESTAURANTDB", "src_id":"308701"}

I am unable to fetch data with geo_near.

Answer (score 0):

sms = SideMongo.where(hide: 0).geo_near([lng.to_f,lat.to_f], max_distance: dis.to_i, unit: "km".to_sym, spherical: true).sort_by!{|r| r.geo[:distance] }